# ¿Como cambiar el CSS del documento segun el resultado de un ITEM en Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

soy nuevo en stackoverflow, estoy creando un chat y quiero cambiar los estilos de los  ,

, , dependiendo el valor que me devuelva el item.

Todo funciona perfectamente, solo quiero poder cambiar los estilos dependiendo el valor de la function result.

```
            <script>
        var from = null, start = 0, url = 'chatmsj.php';
        $(document).ready(function () {
            from = prompt("Escribe tu nombre malandro, pa probar esta vaina");
            load();

            $('form').submit(function (e) {
                $.post(url, {    
                    message: $('#message').val(),
                    from: from
                });
                $('#message').val('');
                return false;

            })
         });

            function load(){
                $.get(url + '?start=' + start, function(result){
                    if(result.items){
                        result.items.forEach(item =>{
                            start = item.id;
                            $('#messages').append(renderMessage(item));
                        });
                        $('#messages').animate({scrollTop: $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight});
                    };
                    load();
                });
            }

            function renderMessage(item){
                let time = new Date(item.created);
                time = `${time.getHours()}:${time.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : ''}${time.getMinutes()}`;


                return `<div class="msg"><p>${item.from}</p>${item.message}<span>${time}</span></div>`;
            }



        </script>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    #messages {
    height: 88vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 10px
    }

    form {
        display: flex
    }

    input {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px 5px;
        appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px
    }
    #message {
        flex: 2
    }
    .msg {
        background-color: #dcf8c6;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        width: fit-content
    }
    .msg p {
        margin: 0;
        font-weight: bold
    }
    .msg span {
        font-size: 0.7rem;
        margin-left: 15px
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="messages">

        </div>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="message" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje...">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
```

Quier poder cambiar el estilo, por ejemplo, quiero que enviar mensajes como ADMIN al chat, y que ADMIN tenga un color de fondo del div diverente al de los demas miembros del chat.

Soy novato en jquery. Habia hecho un chat con ajax y php, refrescando la web con consultas a cada instante, pero obviamente eso va a reventar el server.

Saludos y espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el css de un selector con jquery puedes utilizar la función .css(). Ejemplo: `$(".selectorPrueba").css("color","black")`
Te dejo la doc: https://api.jquery.com/css/. 
De todas maneras, te aconsejo editar tu pregunta y añadir un pequeño ejemplo sencillo de lo que quieres con https://jsfiddle.net/ para que sea más clara.

Comment: Hola, de verdad muchas gracias por responderme. si, conozco css(), pero no se como estructurarlo, el codigo que subi es de un chat que estoy haciendo, pero quiero que cuando cuando yo hable con alguien, por ejemplo JUAN(yo) PEDRO(amigo), El div que devuelve RETURN cambie de color y caracteristicas segun el valor que tenga {item:from}. ¿Me explique bien?.

Comment: Si lo estoy entendiendo bien, yo en tu lugar al identificaría de alguna manera a los usuarios, por ejemplo item.id y como el chat es de 2 (entiendo) a la <p> donde pones el item.from le puedes añadir una clase, por ejemplo <p class="usuario"+item.id >item.from</p>, entonces te creas dos clases .usuario1 { color:pink;}, .usuario2{color:blue;} y lo tendrías. Esto es una idea básica de como podrías hacerlo, pegale una vuelta para hacerlo mejor y mas dinámico.